# get orders by date using REST endpoints

Tags: magento2, php, rest-api

I'm trying to get all orders on a specific date, as an example, I'm trying to get all orders at 28th of June 2020.

But my problem is that I get a total count of 0 even though there's orders at that date.

```
<?php

$ch  = curl_init('https://domain.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=x&password=x');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// get admin token
$token = curl_exec($ch);

$headers = array(
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
"Authorization: Bearer ".$token
);

$api_request = 'https://domain.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2020-06-28&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
';
$curl = curl_init($api_request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo curl_exec($curl);




?>
```

I need to get json contains all orders details so I can loop through each order items.

The above peice of code is not working, I try to excute the request using Postman, if someone could try to run this code that would be great.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

change the value of `$api_request`

```
$api_request = 'https://domain.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2020-06-28 00:00:00&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq;
```

Pass value of `created_at` like this - **2020-06-28 00:00:00**, Instead of **2020-06-28**

Comment: I still get total count of 0 in postman, plus my above piece of code doesn't work I get empty page as an ouput.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with between both dates the day your seek and the next that you can calculate:

```
$date = $params['date'];
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$day = date('d', $timestamp);
$month = date('m', $timestamp);
$year = date('Y', $timestamp);
$nextDay = sprintf('%s-%s-%s', $year, $month, $day + 1);
```

either like the one line style you use:

```
 searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2020-06-28&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=gt&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=2020-06-29&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=lt
```

or like the below is more readable for me..

```
 $params = new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters([
            'searchCriteria' => [
                'filterGroups' => [
                    0 => [
                        'filters' => [
                            0 => [
                                'field' => 'created_at',
                                'value' => $input->getArgument('date'),
                                'condition_type' => 'gt'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    1 => [
                        'filters' => [
                            0 => [
                                'field' => 'created_at',
                                'value' => $this->getNextDay($input->getArgument('date')),
                                'condition_type' => 'lt'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'current_page' => 1,
                'page_size' => 10
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

> **rest/all/V1/orders**

```
https://example.com/rest/all/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2020-06-28 00:00:00&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using eq as condition. Need to use gt or lt.